# how do I link TextBox's AutoCompleteSource to entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, autocomplete, textbox

I've a table "Clients", and a textbox named tbClient, but i dont know how to implement autocomplete using entity framework and LINQ on the textbox. this is what i've actually

```
 var client = from a in ca.Clients select new { a.Name, a.DNI, a.Address, a.Phone, a.Email};
 var cli = client.ToList();
 dgvClient.DataSource = cli;
```

to fill the datagridview

Comment: do you know how to use `Google` you could have done a `C# msdn Search on TextBox AutoComplete` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solved

```
var name = from a in ca.Clients select a.Name;
AutoCompleteStringCollection sourcename = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
sourcename.AddRange(name.ToArray());
this.tbName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
this.tbName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
this.tbName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = sourcename;
```